# How to make Symfony2 read php native session directly

Tags: session, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app and I have to read the sessions set from another, non-symfony app.

The non-symfony app just set its sessions into `$_SESSION`, as usual.

However, when I attempt to read this session, the data isn't there. No matter I do it by

```
$session = $this->get('request')->getSession();
var_dump($session->all());
```

or even (I know I shouldn't do this, but anyway)

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and this gives me session already started error, and I have no idea why there is error despite I have never started session in the Symfony app. Tells me if this way actually work so that I can look into `session_start()` thing.

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
var_dump($session->all());
```

The `PHPSESSID` cookie is set in the Symfony2 app and its value is the same as the cookie set in the non-symfony app, but my Symfony2 app just refuse to read the content of the session. (`$session->getName()` returns `PHPSESSID`, to be clear)

(To be exact, both apps are under same domain but different subdomains, and I have already set `framework.session.domain` correctly in `app/config.yml` in Symfony app and called `session_set_cookie_params` on the non-symfony app to have the same domain setting to allow sharing session cookie between subdomains i.e. `.example.com`)

So how do you read sessions in a Symfony2 app/Controller that is set by a non-symfony app? Thanks.

I am using Symfony 2.1, if this matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use the native Symfony2 session wrapper classes because they read session data from `app/cache/{env}/sessions/{session_id}`, and your non-Symfony2 app isn't writing its session data to that location.

You could write a custom session handler in your non-Symfony2 app that writes to that location, or better still you could write a native session handler class in Symfony2 which bypasses the default Symfony2 session read location and gets it from the default PHP session path

EDIT: Since writing this answer there is now a much more elegant solution available in gadbout's post below.

Answer (score 8):

No need to write a custom session handler, the native one from Symfony2 can directly read/write from the default PHP $_SESSION.

In config.yml of your Symfony2 app, add a save_path option as below:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: ~
```

Clean the cache, and now your sessions will be saved in the default PHP path instead of the Symfony2 sessions folder. You can now share data, that's what I did to login data between a new Sf2 app and an old Sf1 app.

Comment: this works for me.  I think this should be the correct answer for the question and it sure beats writing a new session handler.

Comment: this is indeed a much better solution

Comment: An excelente solution. And it is working in symfony3 as well. Thank you very much.